# HttpBasicAuthenticator Authentication Issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, restful-authentication

I have just started to work on 3rd party API Integration. In the Postman Client API Call, I have used authorization key in the header and bearer with token. When I started to integrate with my C# code. I used HttpBasicAuthenticator to authenticate the API with access token. But it automatically appends "basic" as String with the token instead of that I want it to append "bearer".

Can you please help me out. How can I do that?

Help is appreciated. Thanks

```
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(x, string.Format("Bearer {0}",ApiToken));
```

Comment: Which REST Client are you using? RestSharp?

Comment: @JatinParmar Yes, I am using RestSharp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using wrong Authenticator,

If you want to use Bearer token to access the API Endpoint, you can use [JwtAuthenticator](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Authenticators/JwtAuthenticator.cs)

Try,

```
client.Authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator(ApiToken);
```

Which solve your problem.